# Are these constructors correct?

Tags: c++, c++14, move, shared

Are these constructors correct?

Are they well formed and correctly overloaded both for lvalues and rvalues?

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> data;

// lvalue constructor
Obj(std::string const & p_data)
    : data {std::make_shared<std::string>(p_data)}
{}

// rvalue constructor
Obj(std::string && p_data)
    : data {std::make_shared<std::string>(std::move(p_data))}
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

In the move constructor, `std::move(p_data)` is necessary because `p_data` is an lvalue.

Comment: Are you sure about `noexcept`? `make_shared` typically has to allocate memory, and that is an operation that is not `noexcept`.

Comment: @j6t: totally forgot about the `std::shared_ptr` and focused on `std::string`, whoops :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Obj(std::string const & p_data)
>     : data {std::make_shared<std::string>(p_data)}
> {}
> ```

Are you sure that you want *implicit* conversions from `std::string` to `Obj`? If *not*, consider making the constructor [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
// Prevent *implicit* conversions from std::string to Obj
explicit Obj(std::string const& p_data)
    : data{std::make_shared<std::string>(p_data)}
{}
```

Comment: That's just an example, the real object has more than one parameter ;)